# YouTube Content ID API : AssetSearch Issue

Tags: youtube-api

I am working on YouTube Content ID API to fetch assests which are added today.
First of all I try to explore API on YouTube Content ID API explorer and then find asset search suitable for my criteria.So I provided the required parameters and got the response but response include only 25 results each time so I used NextPageToken
recived from response to get next assests,so far so good ,but for all this responses I noticed the ResultsPerPage varies for each request which confused me.As I assumed that ResultsPerPage indicates the all assests for the particular content owner and considering this I decided to code but now I'm unable to decide how should procced.
Can any one help me to understand this

Answer (score 0):

Both the totalResults and ResultsPerPage are not reliable, according to employees at YouTube. You can only rely on the data that comes through. You can verify this with your TAM/Partner Manager.

In order to get the real count of your assets (I'm assuming you're using AssetSearch?), you have to keep paginating until there's no "nextPageToken' in the response, and count your results.

By the way, if you set the parameter "maxResults=50" in your request, you'll get 50 per page (until there's less than 50 left to display, which should only happen on the last page, given that you have a number of assets not divisible by 50).